# Show that $T$ is a topological embedding of $X$ in itself.

Tags: group-theory, metric-spaces, p-adic-number-theory, isometry, automorphism-group

Let $X$ be the set of odd positive fractions with denominator $3$ in lowest terms, except for $\frac13$.

$X=\{x\in\Bbb Q^+:3x\in3\Bbb N\pm1\}\setminus\{\frac13\}$

If $a,b$ are 2-adic units, then any 2-adic number $x$ can be written in the form
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty b_i (2a)^i$$

where $b_i$ is either $b$ or $0$.

Let $T_{a,b}(x)$ be the 2-adic isometry which sends this $x$ to:

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty c_i 2^i$$

where $c_i$ is either $1$ when $b_i=b$, and otherwise remains $0$.

These functions $T_{a,b}(x)$, with the group operation composition, and $a,b$ still ranging over $\Bbb Z_2^\times$, are the isometry group you get generated by changing uniformizer and coefficients from $2a,b$ to $2,1$ while keeping the underlying binary string the same.  The group operation of composition is achieved via multiplication of the two coefficients and the two 2-adic units underlying the uniformizers independently.

**Question**

Show that $T_{3,1}(x)$ is a topological embedding of $X$ in itself. i.e. $T(X)\subset X$.

**My Attempt**

I think anybody attempting this question will have more powerful tools in their kit bag than I, but I have a handful of potentially useful tidbits.

I've arranged the problem so the numbers in the domain and the image of $T$ share the same terminal string or periodic part.  Intuition said that was the way to go.

The proof will possibly hang around looking at a 2-adic number in $X$ as being of the form $-\frac23\cdot2^t+n:t\in\Bbb N, n\in\Bbb N$. Notice that to get a **unique** "factorisation" into $n,t$ we would need to pick the "end" of the string $\overline{01}_2$ to the left.  This is done by realising there are two cases - the string $\overline{01}_2$ must be followed by a one, or by two zeroes.  The $\overline{01}00_2$ case is not of interest as these are negative rationals and therefore not in $X$.  So we're looking at $\overline{01}1_2=\frac13$ and need to show that every value in $X$ is cauchy in $X$ and cannot "cross" the barrier $\frac13\cdot2^t$ under the action of $T$.

Remember the isometry property is in play. This means if we find corresponding pair $x,y$ such that $T(x)=y$ then there is no other $x$ in the domain and there is no other $y$ in the image.

On reflection, even the weaker theorem, that $x$ and $T(x)$ differ by an integer is likely to be sufficient.

Comment: What topology on $X$? You defined it as a subset of the reals, but since everything else is stated about 2-adics, are you topologizing it by the 2-adic metric or the real metric? Or something else?

Comment: 2-adic topology

Comment: Can you recall a definition of a $2$-adic unit?

Comment: @AlexRavsky I'm talking about the elements of $\Bbb Z_2$ which have a multiplicative inverse also in $\Bbb Z_2$ so that's all the $x$ such that $2^{\nu_2(x)}=1$.

Comment: There is a lot of extraneous detail here.

Comment: @SeanEberhard I am required by the downvote-close-delete police to include my own attempts no matter how poor they may be. Is there anything in particulr you would remove?

Comment: I could not possibly comment on my own (negative) opinion of those police, but I rather meant everything above: the definition of $T_{a,b}$ for $b \ne 1$, the group composition rule, the topology -- it's all irrelevant, strictly speaking, to your question whether $T(X) \subset X$.

Comment: @SeanEberhard ah ok. The group rules are what I've been using to start thinking about the problem but as I alluded to further down, I think others will have more appropriate tools and more sophisticated ideas than I, how to proceed.

Comment: @AlexRavsky if you are right then I have put a negative sign in wrongly and I should have written $T_{3,-1}$, but I pored over this for a very long time and was convinced I did it right.  Do you get $T(5/3)=\frac{43}3$ or do you get $T(5/3)=-\frac{43}3$

Comment: Overall the problem is not well-motivated. Why positive rationals only? Why exclude $1/3$? You say this is "actually a very important question" -- really?

Comment: @SeanEberhard According to the recent announcent in [OP's profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/334732/its-a-hire-car-baby), I guess there is a very strong motivation for this problem.

Comment: @OP Are you able to evaluate $T = T_{3,1}$ at any element of $X$? In my opinion the details of any such calculation would have been far more useful detail to include in the body of the question. Computing $T(x)$ requires finding the "base-6" expansion of a 2-adic number, which is a bit unusual (though well-defined), and I see no reason that elements of $X$ should have nice expansions in base 6.

Comment: @SeanEberhard the negative ternary rationals land elsewhere. Some such as $-1$ land in $N$, some such as $-1/3$ land in $-\Bbb N$. Some such as $-5$ land among other rationals like $\Bbb Z/7$. The motivation behind picking $X$ is that it is a topological embedding, they share the same periodic part and I think that makes it easier to prove because one can fix the periodic part and prove the residue converges.  Anyway, to answer your other question, the most useful evaluated point is probably $T(1/3)=-1/3$

Comment: @SeanEberhard that's really useful for me to learn, thank-you, re base $6$.  Re "not expecting to behave nicely". If you do look closer, I expect you will find that there is something in the parity of the $\overline{01}_2$ string which behaves nicely between $X$ and its image, which makes the map give nice representations. I don't know exactly what that "nicely" is yet.

Comment: @SeanEberhard your base $6$ point got me thinking and I think I have made an error in this question - the premise is incorrect.  I think I have wasted your time.  The uniformizer does not behave how I thought it did.

Answer (score 2):

In sharp contradiction, I claim that $T(X)$ and $X$ are disjoint. (It doesn't matter if $1/3$ is included -- I don't understand the reason it was excluded. I suspect there were some miscalculations by OP.)

Every $2$-adic integer has a unique representation of the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n 2^n$ with each $b_n \in \{0,1\}$ and also a representation of the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n 6^n$ with each $b_n \in \{0,1\}$. I will refer to the former representation as the base-2 expansion and the latter as the base-6 expansion. The map $T:\mathbf Z_2 \to \mathbf Z_2$ is defined by $T(\sum_n b_n 6^n) = \sum_n b_n 2^n$.

The fact that $T(X) \cap X = \emptyset$ follows from the following two claims.

*Claim 1:* Each element of $X$ (indeed any rational number) has a repeating base-2 expansion.

*Claim 2:* Each element of $X$ has a non-repeating base-6 expansion.

The proof of Claim 1 is completely standard. Here is one way of proving it. Let $q$ be a rational. Then $-q$ has a repeating base-2 expansion in $\mathbf R$. This implies that we have a represenation of $-q$ of the form
$$-q = \alpha + \beta (1 + 1/2^k + 1/2^{2k} + \cdots) = \alpha + \beta / (1-1/2^k)$$
with $\alpha \in \mathbf Z[1/2]$ (i.e., $\alpha$ is a rational with a finite base-2 expansion) and $\beta$ is an integer with $0 \le \beta < 2^k$. Now this implies that, 2-adically,
$$q = -\alpha + \beta 2^k / (1-2^k) = -\alpha + \beta (2^k + 2^{2k} + 2^{3k} +\cdots),$$
which shows that $q$ has a repeating base-2 expansion in $\mathbf Z_2$.

The proof of Claim 2 is similar. Let $n$ be an integer and suppose $n/3$ has a repeating 2-adic base-6 expansion. Then we have a representation of the form
$$n/3 = \alpha + \beta (1 + 6^k + 6^{2k} + \cdots) = \alpha + \beta / (1-6^k),$$
where $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbf Z$. But the right-hand side is a rational number with $3$-adic valuation $\ge 0$, so $n$ must be divisible by $3$.

Comment: Thanks for looking at my problem. I will still parse what you wrote as it will be good practice for me.

Comment: Sorry Sean I tried to notify you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4780107/show-that-t-is-a-topological-embedding-of-x-in-itself/4781926#comment10163681_4780107 I'll award you the bounty when I can.  This comment here indicates the cause of the error: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455325/is-this-submonoid-of-the-isometry-group-on-bbb-q-2-closed-to-inverses#comment1180735_455713 .  It was your comments about base $6$ which made the penny drop that I had misunderstood the uniformizer.

Comment: @it'sahirecarbaby I am not surprised there is confusion, but your question is still a well-formed (if unmotivated) question about a specific function, so I thought it should be answered anyway.

Comment: I think this is going to be helpful in spite of my error.